# R in 3NF if and only if R in BCNF?

Tags: database, primary-key, functional-dependencies, 3nf, bcnf

Consider a relation `R`, and a functional dependencies set `F` ,including only one functional dependency: `{X->A}`.
prove that if R in 3NF iff R in BCNF.

So far, for the <- direction is trivial by definition. But i struggle to the -> direction. What we know about `F-closure`? from the definition, i need to check for every functional dependency `Y->B` that in `F-closure`, that its trivial or Y is superkey. Is there some conclusions on the superkey of R that i'm missing?

Comment: This sounds like a homework questions, stackoverflow doesn't solve homework questions for students

Comment: @ChrisMarisic it sounds like i agree, but its not. if it really bothers you, i really tried to solve by myself. I'll edit.

Comment: Please show what you've done to solve it

Comment: It is not clear from your question how F relates to the FDs that could be in your relaton. F can't be a closure because {A}->{A} isn't in it. Maybe it is a canonical cover, ie the closure is exactly the FDs that must be present when its are. Without clarifying this the question cannot be answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sketch of the proof.

The fact that a relation schema in BCNF implies that the schema is also in 3NF is due to the definition of 3NF (each determinant is a superkey or implies only prime attributes, and we know that each determinant is a superkeys since the schema is in BCNF).

So we must show that if the relation is in 3NF, then it is also in BCNF.

Now consider the only dependency, `{X->A}`. For the definition of 3NF, either `X` is a superkey, or `A` is prime.

In the first case, if `X` is a superkey, we know that the schema is also in BCNF.

So, we need to check only the case in which `X` is not a (super)key, and `A` is prime.
We can prove that this case is impossible, with the following steps.

We have only two possibilities, either `X` contains `A`, or not.

1. If `X` contains `A` then this dependency is trivial, and, since there are no other dependencies, `X` is a key, and this violates our hypothesis, so we have a contradiction.
2. If, on the other hand, `X` is not contained in `A`, then `X` is again a key, and this again contradicts our hypothesis.

Finally, note that in this proof I have assumed that there are no other attributes in `R` a part from `XU{A}`, otherwise those other attributes should be present in any key of the relation, and there should be at least another dependency with them.